# How to automatically print the value of a variable after an assignment?

Tags: r

I read somewhere that there is a way (with some char at the beginning or at the end of the line), which forces an automatic print result of the expression.

I want to automatically print `n`, i.e. without having to type `n` after `n <- 3`

```
n <- 3
n
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If you put the expression in parentheses the result will be printed:

```
(n <- 3)
##[1] 3
```

This works because the assignment operator `<-` returns the value (invisibly, which strangely is not in the documentation). Putting it in parentheses (or in `print` or `c`, or `show`, or `cat` (without newline)) makes it visible.

This "printing behaviour" of `(` is documented in `?"("`:

> For `(`, the result of evaluating the argument. This has visibility set, so will auto-print if used at top-level.

Comment: I am wondering... Is there any disadvantages of doing this ? Since I nearly never see anyone print their objects in this way, while this is quite useful and more "efficient" in my opinion

Comment: I don't think there are any disadvantages. It is also very useful to print the results of functions that return invisible objects, e.g. I often use `(load("datafile.RData"))` to directly see the name of the variables that are loaded.

Comment: @alko989 interesting to know.